# Does point $(0,0)$ belong to solution?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to find set of points satisfying the given condition: $\arg(z)=\frac{\pi}{3}$.

> And my question is: does the point $(0,0)$ belong to this set?

I'm having this problem because my professor defined $\varphi$ as:
$$\cos(\varphi)=\frac{\Re(z)}{|z|}\wedge \sin(\varphi)=\frac{\Im(z)}{|z|}$$
so if $\Re(z)=0 \wedge \Im(z)=0$ then $|z|=0$ and we can't divide by $0$, and at this point my problem comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argument of $0$ is undefined. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis))!

Strictly, the argument function is this form: $\arg:\mathbb C-\{0\}\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: So if I had another example as: $arg(z+2)=\frac{\pi}{3}$ then point (-2,0) is undefind? And if I'd like to graph this solution should I mark this undefind points somehow (for example making small circle around this point) or leave it as it is (not marking it)?

Comment: @Cariweb Yes. In that case, $z=2$ is the point that undefined. In graph, making small circle aroud the undefined point is better.